# Chartboost and Admob in the same app

Tags: android, admob, chartboost

I have developed a game prank application and i have already added AdMob 
advertisements in it....

I wish though to add Chartboost adveritisements too but i don't know if it is
legal to integrate in my app to differenent networks...

Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can add as many networks as you want. I hope you have registered on admob.com and have added your site / app there.

Under "Site & Apps" look for "Ad Network Mediation" and ADD a new network mediation.

You can select from the list of networks, If you network is not in that list (i dont think Chartboost is) you can select "ADD CUSTOM EVENT" and add your network in that mediation placement.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is legal to show both; it is called mediation. If mediation is still a foreign concept to you, please scan over the paragraph below:

> With AdMob Mediation, you can serve ads to your apps from multiple
>   sources, including the AdMob Network, third-party ad networks, and
>   house ad campaigns. AdMob Mediation helps maximize your fill rate and
>   increase your monetization by sending ad requests to multiple networks
>   to ensure you find the best available network to serve ads.

(Source: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3124703)

Also, I just wanted to update this  thread by stating that ChartBoost is now integrated into AdMob (Source: https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/209756523-Mediation-AdMob)

[image: ChartBoost-AdMob integration]

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: Oki, dokes. I have rewrote the answer :)